# C - Ignore spaces in scanf()

Tags: c, algorithm, scanf

I'm trying to make a simple string acquisition. What i need is to write a string from input (stdin), which can contain spaces, and save it **without** any spaces between words.

So far i've written this simple code which saves everything (also spaces), but i don't know how to make the `scanf()` ignore the spaces.

```
int main(){
    char str[10];
    scanf("%[^\n]s, str);
    printf("%s", str;
}
```

**For example**:

if my input is: `I love C programming!` my output should be: `IloveCprogramming!`

I tried to use `%*`, used to ignore characters, but without any success.

I also know that i could "rescan" the string once is saved and remove all the spaces, but i need to do this acquisition as efficient as possible, and rescan every string to remove the spaces will increase the computational time a lot (instead of just scanning and ignoring, which has complexity of O(n))

Comment: "rescan every string to remove the spaces will increase the computational time a lot" - no it won't? You just need two pointers, a source and destination, and you can do this in place: move the two pointers down the string; if the character at source is not whitespace then copy it to destination and advance both pointers (can shortcut here if source == dest still); if it is whitespace, just advance source; if it's 0, copy that then stop. That's O(n).

Comment: And I would be very surprised if you could get scanf to ignore the spaces for you.

Comment: Yes you're right, but i would need 2 arrays to do that! I was wondering if it's possible to just ignore the whitespaces during scanf (as you can ignore a string using %*s %s, the scanf will ignore the first string)

Comment: I don't think so, but someone else might know how. You don't need two arrays since the destination pointer will always be <= the source pointer so you can modify your original array as you iterate through. But even if you did need two arrays, a small amount of temporary allocation isn't inefficient in the grand scheme of things, particularly if you can reuse it for all of your many strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far i've written this simple code which saves everything (also
>   spaces), but i don't know how to make the `scanf()` ignore the spaces.

You're coming at this from the opposite direction of what most new C programmers do.  The problem is not usually to make `scanf` skip spaces, as it does that by default for most types of field, and in particular for `%s` fields.  Spaces are ordinarily recognized as field delimiters, so not only are leading spaces skipped, but also spaces are not read inside fields.  I presume that it is because you know this that you are using a `%[` field.

But you cannot have your cake and eat it too.  The field directive `%[^\n]` says that the data to be read consist of a run of non-newline characters.  `scanf` will faithfully read all such characters *and transfer them to the array you designate*.  You do not have the option to instruct `scanf` to avoid transferring some of the characters that you told it were part of the field.

If you want to continue to use `scanf` then you have two options:

- remove the spaces after you read the data, or
- read and transfer the space-separated pieces as separate fields.

Another answer already describes how to do the former.  Here's how you might do the latter:

```
int main(void) {
    int field_count;

    do {
        char str[80];
        char tail;

        field_count = scanf("%79[^ \n]%c", str, &tail));
        if (field_count == 0) {
            // No string was scanned this iteration: the first available char
            // was a space or newline.  Consume it, then proceed appropriately.
            field_count = scanf("%c", &tail);
            if (field_count != 1 || tail == '\n') {
                // newline, end-of-file, or error: break out of the loop
                break;
            } // else it's a space -- ignore it
        } else if (field_count > 0) {
            // A string was scanned; print it:
            printf("%s", str);

            if (field_count == 2) {
                // A trailing character was scanned, too; take appropriate action:
                if (tail == '\n') {
                    break;
                } else if (tail != ' ') {
                    putchar(tail);
                } // else it is a space; ignore it
            }
        } // else field_count == EOF
    } while (field_count != EOF);
}
```

***Things to note***:

- The 79-character (maximum) field width in the `scanf` `%79[^ \n]` directive.  Without a field width, there is a serious risk of overrunning your array bound (which must be at least one character longer than the field to allow for a string terminator).
- `[` is a field type, not a qualifier.  `s` is a separate field type that also handles strings, but has different behavior; no `s` field is used here.
- `scanf`'s return value tells you how many fields were successfully scanned, which can be fewer than are described in the format string in the event that a mismatch occurs between input and format, or the end of the input is reached, or an I/O error occurs.  These possibilities need to be taken into account.
- In the event that the second field, `%c`, is in fact scanned, it allows you to determine whether the preceding string field ended because the field width was exhausted without reaching a space or newline, because a space was observed, or because a newline was observed.  Each of these cases requires different handling.
- Although `scanf` skips leading whitespace for *most* field types, `%[` and `%c` fields are two of the three exceptions.
- This approach skips space characters (`' '`) specifically; it does not skip other whitespace characters such as horizontal and vertical tabs, carriage returns, form feeds, etc..  This approach could be adapted to handle those, too, but what is presented is sufficient to demonstrate.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong tool for the job. You need to use [getc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getc/)

And do the following

```
int ch;
char str[10];

// Loop until either loop reaches 9 (need one for null character) or EOF is reached
for (int loop = 0; loop < 9 && (ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF; ) {
   if (ch != ' ' ) {
     str[loop] = ch;
     ++loop;
   }
}
str[loop] = 0;

printf("%s", str);
```

No re-scan required

Comment: So it's impossible to ignore spaces via scanf? I thought about this solution, but i was curious if scanf supports that feature

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio - cannot think of any way with `scanf`

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio:  No, there’s no (standard) conversion specifier that will do what you want.  That’s frankly a very uncommon use case.

Comment: @EdHeal, I guess whether the problem can be solved with `scanf` depends on how you characterize it.  Certainly `getc` or `getchar` affords the simplest code I can think of to perform the OP's desired transformation of input to output, but you can use (primarily) `scanf()` to do that job, too.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - I am looking forward to seeing the code

Comment: @EdHeal, well then just scroll down

Comment: I would say that depending on what someone is actually doing, they probably want a regex engine (`regex.h` or PCRE) or a parser generator (flex+bison) instead of either scanf or getc.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf()` is not useful for your purpose, indeed you do not even need a buffer to strip spaces from a line of input: just read bytes one at a time, ignore the spaces, output the others and stop at newline or EOF:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != ' ') {
            putchar(c);
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note also that your code has problems:

- the `scanf()` format string is unterminated
- the trailing `s` is incorrect, the format is simply `%[^\n]`
- it is safer to specify the maximum number of bytes to store into the array before the null terminator: `scanf("%9[^\n]", str);`
- you should test the return value of `scanf()` to avoid passing an uninitialize array to `printf` if the conversion fails, for example on an empty line or an empty file.

You could use `scanf()` as an inefficient way too read characters while ignoring white space, with `char c; while (scanf(" %c", &c) == 1) { putchar(c); }` but you would be unable to detect the end of line.

Answer (score 2):

If interested in removing other white space from input (in addition to '') you can also incorporate the C library function *[isspace(.)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isspace.htm)*, which tests for the following standard white space characters:

> ' '   (0x20)  space (SPC)
>   '\t'  (0x09)  horizontal tab (TAB)
>   '\n'  (0x0a)  newline (LF)
>   '\v'  (0x0b)  vertical tab (VT)
>   '\f'  (0x0c)  feed (FF)
>   '\r'  (0x0d)  carriage return (CR)

This example incorporates function using the `isspace(.);` library function, and provides a method to clear all standard white space from a C string.

```
int main(void)
{
    char string[] = {"this contain's \n whitespace\t"};
    int len = strlen(string);
    char out[len+1];// +1 for null terminator 
                    //(accommodates when input contains no whitespace)
    int count = clean_whitespace(string, out);

    return 0;
}

int clean_whitespace(const char *in, char *out)
{
    int len, count=0, i;
    if((in) && (out))
    {
        len = strlen(in);
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            if(!isspace(in[i]))
            {
                out[count++] = in[i];
            }
        }
        out[count]=0;//add null terminator.
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this to demonstrate that it is also possible to solve this problem just with scanf.

```
 int main() {
   char a[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
        scanf("%c", &a[i]);
        if( a[i] == ' ')
        i--;
    }
}
```

the one above simply scans 10 characters without the spaces inbetween.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
       printf("%c,", a[i]);
     }

    printf("%c", a[9]);
```

and this is the way to use if you want to replace the spaces with something else, for example: ' , '

If you want the input to consist of more characters, simply define a new variable x and change the 10 into x, and the 9's into x-1

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here's a simple version using scanf():

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buff[10];
    int r;

    r = 1;
    scanf("%*[ ]");

    while (r == 1) {
        r = scanf("%9[^ \n]%*[ ]", buff);
        if (r == 1) fputs(buff, stdout);
    }

    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

What this does:

- `scanf("%*[ ]")`: skip initial whitespace, if any (requested format: non empty sequence of spaces, without storing it in a variable), ignoring the result.
- `r = scanf("%9[^ \n]%*[ ]", buff)`: read two requested formats (explained below) and return number of successful conversions.

  - `%9[^ \n]`: requested format: up to 9 characters of contiguous text (read up to newline).
  - `%*[ ]`: requested format: non empty sequence of spaces, without storing it in a variable.
- `if (r == 1) fputs(buff, stdout)`: check if some text was read (1 successful conversion from `scanf()`). If it was, output it.

This is executed in a loop until a text slice cannot be read anymore. Optionally, the final `\n` can be read with `getchar()`.

Example execution:

```
$ ./scanstring 
             abcd          xyz        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa    wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww      zzzzz 1234567891011121314             !!!
abcdxyzaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwzzzzz1234567891011121314!!!
```

`scanf()` manual: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html